# downloading a file and then renaming it

Tags: php, ftp

Rather than downloading a file straight, I decide to just download a file via ftp and then rename the downloaded file to the correct name. That way the time where the file is malfunctioning is minimal.

Here is the "essence" of the code

```
$status=ftp_get($conn_id, $temp , $filename, $mode);
rename ( $temp , $filename );
```

I basically got an error saying that file $temp is in use so can't rename.

The thing is the download is finish.

Should I close the file or something? How to tell PhP, hello, $temp is done, now I need to rename it.

This is the more comprehensive version of the code

```
function dealWithOneFile($filename,$conn_id)
{
    $ftpsize = ftp_size ($conn_id, $filename);

    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if ($ext == "php" || $ext == "bin" || $ext == "dat" || $ext == "BIN" || $ext == "inc")
    {
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }

    while(false)
    if (file_exists ($filename ))
    {
        $filesize =filesize ($filename);

        if ($filesize==$ftpsize)
        {
            echo "file size is the same with the one we have here\n";
            return;
        }
    }
    $temp = "temp.bin";

    $mode= FTP_BINARY;

    if ($ext=="php")
    {
        $mode = FTP_ASCII ;
    }

    $status=ftp_get($conn_id, $temp , $filename, $mode);

    if ($status) {
        echo "Successfully written $filename to $temp\n";
        if (file_exists($filename))
        {

            $tempsize = filesize ($temp);

            if ($filesize==$tempsize)
            {
                echo "file size is the same with the one we have here\n";
                return;
            }
        }
        while(false);
        //unlink ($filename);
        rename ( $temp , $filename );

        echo "Succesfully update $filename \n";     
    } else {
        echo "There was a problem\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My current solution that actually works is to sleep 5 minutes before rename.

I want better solutions. But this is definitely an answer.